# How to create an Handle (not event handler) in VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6

Is there a way to create an handle in VB6? Also, is there a way to listen on this handle via VB6?

I am using a program in C#.NET to set value on a handle, but I do not know which handle is to be set..

I have tried to use C#.net and created handler using Me.CreateHandle; however I have to implement it in VB6...

Comment: In vb6 you will have `API`s so you can do the kernal level things through `API`s.

Comment: I have completed this task. Please refer to my answer on how I achieved it. Its an window handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Function WindowProc; MSDN article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us). It allows you to catch messages.